# Nuxt 3 file upload and store in locally in the project

Tags: file-upload, nuxt.js, vuejs3, multipartform-data

I want to create a simple Nuxt 3 file upload implementation that stores the file in the locally in a folder in the Nuxt project. In PHP the server side code is very easy and straight forward but I am finding it difficult doing the same thing in Nuxt 3 server side.

Comment: In Nuxt, it's as easy. Check a tutorial on how to achieve that with Node.js or provide more effort regarding what you already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better alternative using https://github.com/wobsoriano/h3-formidable

```
import { readFiles } from 'h3-formidable';
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const { files: { photo: [ { filepath, mimetype } ] } } = await readFiles(event, {
         includeFields: true
    });

    let imageName = String(Date.now()) + String(Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000));
    let newPath = `${path.join("public", "uploads", imageName)}.${ mimetype.split('/')[1] }`;
    fs.copyFileSync(filepath, newPath);

    return { success: true }
});
```

Comment: Have you tested it in production? It does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

**First:**

`npm install formidable`

**second:**

define formidable in **Nuxt config** file inside modules list.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
modules: ["formidable"],
});
```

then in your handler for example upload.post.js :

```js
import formidable from "formidable";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  let imageUrl = "";
  let oldPath = "";
  let newPath = "";

  const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(event.req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      if (!files.photo) {
        resolve({
          status: "error",
          message: "Please upload a photo with name photo in the form",
        });
      }
      if (files.photo.mimetype.startsWith("image/")) {
        let imageName =
          Date.now() +
          Math.round(Math.random() * 100000) +
          files.photo.originalFilename;
        oldPath = files.photo.filepath;
        newPath = `${path.join("public", "uploads", imageName)}`;
        imageUrl = "./public/upload/" + imageName;
        fs.copyFileSync(oldPath, newPath);
        resolve({
          status: "ok",
          url: imageUrl,
        });
      } else {
        resolve({
          status: "error",
          message: "Please upload nothing but images.",
        });
      }
    });
  });
  return data;
});
```

don't forget to name the input field "photo" in the client side or change it here in every "files.photo".
ALso the path of uploaded photos will be in public/uploads directory you can change it too if you like in "path.join" method.
Good luck

Comment: event.req is depreciated in nuxt 3.

Comment: @Horizon try `event.node.req`.

Comment: how can I associate this code with additional fields appended, and run mongodb queries?

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an example of how to do this to get a multiple file upload in back-end:**

```
//server/api/index.post.js
import { MediasModel } from "./../../models/Medias.model";
import { readFiles } from "h3-formidable";
import { firstValues } from "h3-formidable/helpers";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  // create media directory if it doesn't exist
  if (!fs.existsSync("public/uploads")) {
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join("public", "uploads"));
  }

  const { fields, form, files } = await readFiles(event, {
    includeFields: true,
    multiples: true,
    maxFiles: 10,
    maxFilesSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
    maxFields: 8,
    filter: function ({ name, originalFilename, mimetype }) {
      // keep only images and pdf's
      return (
        mimetype && (mimetype.includes("image") || mimetype.includes("pdf"))
      );
    },
  });

  // Gets first values of fields
  const exceptions = ["thisshouldbeanarray"];
  const fieldsSingle = firstValues(form, fields, exceptions);

  const name = fieldsSingle.name;
  let value = files.value || fieldsSingle.value;
  const tag = fieldsSingle.tag;
  const type = fieldsSingle.type;

  // Save media archive
  let listFiles = [];
  if (files.value) {
    for (const file of files.value) {
      const fileName = `${Date.now()}-${file.newFilename}-${
        file.mimetype.split("/")[1]
      }`;
      const newPath = `${path.join("public", "uploads", fileName)}`;
      fs.copyFileSync(file.filepath, newPath);
      listFiles.push(fileName);
    }
    value = listFiles;
  }

  // Create new media in model
  const media = await MediasModel.create({
    name,
    value,
    tag,
    type,
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Without any need to use any third party service, you can use this:

(Say you have this code in `upload.post.ts` in `/server/api` folder)

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const files = await readMultipartFormData(event)

  const uploadedFilePaths: string[] = []

  files?.forEach((file) => {
    const filePath = path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      'public',
      file.filename as string,
    )
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, file.data)
    uploadedFilePaths.push(`/${file.filename}`)
  })

  return uploadedFilePaths
})
```

Here with some formdata uploading files, setting name as key and placing files inside value, you can upload files, and store them inside public folder.